# Store JSON output of personality insights in a file using Java

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, personality-insights

I downloaded the personality insights java code from github and I made some changes to the code on hub.jazz. My question is how do I get the results from the personality insights saved into either a database or locally?

Comment: Have you tried anything and got stuck? A small tutorial on File IO would show you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Showing your research, including what you have tried and what is not working, puts the question into a scope appropriate for SO.  Currently your question is lacking these things and may get down voted.

Comment: @4castle I haven't actually looked at a File IO. I'll do that and if I get stuck I'll post the code I used and the help I need. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @JECarterII thank you for you advice. I shall do that as soon as I've tried the File IO option.

Comment: @4castle I've done some research on the File IO. From what I'm seeing the app has to be running locally. What happens if its a web app? I've pushed the app up to Bluemix and would like to store the results every time a user analyzes their personality.

Answer (score 0):

The results from the Personality Insights service are returned in JSON which you can just serialize to a file (or less common, you can return the result as CSV which is even easier - just use a FileWriter to save).
Specific code will depend on the JSON library you are using. I'd suggest to just "google" saving a json file in Java and you'll have a bunch of examples and videos.